# Convert a raw RGB array into a png image.

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to read a image file using PIL and then obtaining the raw pixel values in form of numpy array and then i am trying to put together the values to form a copy of original image. The code does not produce any runtime error but the image formed ("my.png") is unreadable.

```
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

img_filename = "image.png"
img = Image.open(img_filename)
img = img.convert("RGB")
img.show()
aa  = np.array(img.getdata())
alpha = Image.fromarray(aa,"RGB")
alpha.save('my.png')
alpha.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.array(img.getdata())` gives a 2D array of shape `(X, 3)`, where `X` depends on the dimensions of the original image.

Just change the relevant line of code to:

```
aa  = np.array(img)
```

This will assign a 3D array to `aa`, and thus solve your problem.